# Angular Interceptor - Problem in subscribe

Tags: angular, apollo, interceptor

So I have an HTTP interceptor that I use to pass an auth token to the apollo server and also to catch errors from it.

The queries work fine, but when I try to run a mutation using the apollo angular package it gets executed (the data is added to the database) but the subscribe method doesn't get executed. 
I'll let you below my interceptor and also how I call the mutation:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        // return next.handle(req);
        const tokenObservable = this.authService.getToken();

        return tokenObservable.pipe(
            switchMap(token => {
                console.log(token);
                // let nextHandle: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>;
                let newRequest: HttpRequest<any>
                if (token) {
                    newRequest = req.clone({
                        headers: req.headers.set('Authorization', token)
                    });
                } else {
                    newRequest = req;
                }

                return next.handle(newRequest).pipe(
                    tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                            console.log('---event', event);
                            if (event.url === graphQlConfig.url && event.body && event.body.errors && event.body.errors[0].extensions.code === 'UNAUTHENTICATED') {
                                localStorage.removeItem('defaultTeam');
                                this.authService.signOut();
                            }
                        }
                    })
                );
            })
        );
    }
```

and here it is a mutation that I call:

```
 this.addTeamGQL.mutate({
            team_name: this.teamName
        }).pipe(
            tap(e => console.log(e))
        ).subscribe(res => {
            console.log('res', res);
        });
```

Any idea how can I make it work? If in the interceptor I just put `return next.halde(req)` it works. I think the problem is with those 2 observables but I can't figure it out. The `getToken()` method is returning an `Obersable<string | null>`

Comment: `switchMap()` will cancel the previous subscription when the next value is emitted. I'm not sure that's happening, but I would add a `pipe(first(), switchMap(..))` so that you only get a single token.